# Wordpress custom links not working properly

Tags: wordpress, menuitem

I created a menu item with custom link (empty URL). I tried using # in the URL and it works fine (no navigation) but when i remove the # the it tries to navigate to what i typed in the label text and returns - obviously - a 404.

Please advice!!

Comment: Can you please share what you have attempted. Example of the link etc.

Comment: the page is not live yet but i can explain..
menu items are Home - Services - About us.
Under services there are sub items: design - print - logos
I need the services parent to be not clickable so i created a custom link with the text label "Services". When URL is removed it still navigates to the "services" which is not exist as a page or post.. it is just the text label for the custom link

Comment: Why not just keep the # in there then?

Comment: when i keep the # it is shown in the address bar as: http://localhost/artelion/#. is there a way not to show this in the address bar?

Comment: maybe this will be resolved when i go live?

Answer (score 0):

When you use a custom link, you need to add #ElementID or write the full link(or relative link).

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
So is there a way to make my menu like the example:
http://a2b.com.cy/
when services is click nothing happens and nothing is added in the address bar such as "/#"
Also when you click on the a2b logo (top-left) you can see on the bottom bar a2b.com.cy/# but nothing happens in the address bar (browser)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out using the `javascript:void(0)` suggestion in Kyon147 post.

Added this code in functions.php file:

```
add_filter('walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'wpse_226884_replace_hash', 999);
/**
 * Replace # with js
 * @param string $menu_item item HTML
 * @return string item HTML
 */
function wpse_226884_replace_hash($menu_item) {
    if (strpos($menu_item, 'href="#"') !== false) {
        $menu_item = str_replace('href="#"', 'href="javascript:void(0);"', $menu_item);
    }
    return $menu_item;
}
```

It works but will this affect my site in any way?